# Preferences Libgdx Java

Tags: java, android, libgdx, preferences

I have been trying to implement a high score feature into my Libgdx game, using getPreferences to save the scores. When i run the program as a desktop app it saves the scores after the initial use, however when i close it and re-run it these scores do not remain. **Will it remain completely even it the program is terminated when the game is published to android, ios, desktop etc?**

Here is the code that I am using:

```
Preferences scores = Gdx.app.getPreferences("High Scores");


int currentHighScore = scores.getInteger("currentHighScore", 0);
                        if(currentHighScore < gamescore){
                        scores.putInteger("currentHighScore", gamescore);

int currentHighScore = scores.getInteger("currentHighScore",0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure you call `flush()` before the application exits. Adding `scores.flush()` after you call `putInteger(...)` should be sufficient.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences